# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: from the class org.springframework.aop.framework.cglibaopproxy#

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to call a SOAP end Point from a Spring boot set and webFlux. `Mono.fromcallable()` it fails, but when I call the soap end point in the standard way that works.

Using the same type of SOAP call from stream and standard way

```
webServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(String uriString,
                                 WebServiceMessageCallback requestCallback,
                                 WebServiceMessageExtractor<T> responseExtractor)
```

The Debug point takes to this `CglibAopProxy` class intercept method and fails at `target = targetSource.getTarget();` line with `Null` with following msg

```
@Override
        @Nullable
        public Object intercept(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args, MethodProxy methodProxy) throws Throwable {
            Object oldProxy = null;
            boolean setProxyContext = false;
            Object target = null;
            TargetSource targetSource = this.advised.getTargetSource();
            try {
                if (this.advised.exposeProxy) {
                    // Make invocation available if necessary.
                    oldProxy = AopContext.setCurrentProxy(proxy);
                    setProxyContext = true;
                }
                // Get as late as possible to minimize the time we "own" the target, in case it comes from a pool...
                target = targetSource.getTarget();
                Class<?> targetClass = (target != null ? target.getClass() : null);
                List<Object> chain = this.advised.getInterceptorsAndDynamicInterceptionAdvice(method, targetClass);
                Object retVal;
                // Check whether we only have one InvokerInterceptor: that is,
                // no real advice, but just reflective invocation of the target.
                if (chain.isEmpty() && Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())) {
                    // We can skip creating a MethodInvocation: just invoke the target directly.
                    // Note that the final invoker must be an InvokerInterceptor, so we know
                    // it does nothing but a reflective operation on the target, and no hot
                    // swapping or fancy proxying.
                    Object[] argsToUse = AopProxyUtils.adaptArgumentsIfNecessary(method, args);
                    retVal = methodProxy.invoke(target, argsToUse);
                }
                else {
                    // We need to create a method invocation...
                    retVal = new CglibMethodInvocation(proxy, target, method, args, targetClass, chain, methodProxy).proceed();
                }
                retVal = processReturnType(proxy, target, method, retVal);
                return retVal;
            }
            finally {
                if (target != null && !targetSource.isStatic()) {
                    targetSource.releaseTarget(target);
                }
                if (setProxyContext) {
                    // Restore old proxy.
                    AopContext.setCurrentProxy(oldProxy);
                }
            }
        }

<--
```

Error Log :

> Unable to trigger Master Pricer retrieval:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.wsTemplate': Scope 'session' is
>   not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy
>   for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request
>   found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual
>   web request, or processing a request outside of the originally
>   receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request
>   and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside
>   of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use
>   RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current
>   request. Error in processing Search Live Request {}  :: null
>   com.fly.player.amadeus.orchestrator.exception.FunctionalException

Has any one seen this type of error? Was there a work around? Any hints or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you Autowiring a session-scoped bean in a Singleton? You cannot inject a narrower scoped bean in another wider scoped bean. Change the design of your bean wiring or use scoped-proxy.

Comment: Hi @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar, 
looks like that the issue, will let you know once the fix is completed.  

Thanks very much. --